# Label not showing for checkbox

Tags: reactjs

I have a web project I am writing and I've come across a problem i'm trying to display a check box with a label... the checkbox shows but no label

I've went to https://material-ui.com and found found some code to implement and it shows the Checkbox but no label.

```
    {this.props.value === 3 ? (
      <div>
        <label htmlFor='chkInsulin'>
          <CheckBox name='chkInsulin' /> Take Insulin
        </label>
      </div>
    ) : (
      ''
    )}
```

their are no error message.. what i expect it to do if I enter 3 in the text field it's supposed to show a checkbox with a label... but it shows the checkbox pushed over from center and can't see label can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you consider doing something like this instead:

```
      <FormControlLabel
        control={
          <Checkbox/>
        }
        label="Take Insulin"
      />
```

This is from https://material-ui.com/components/checkboxes/

Comment: I tried that... I don't know if I was missing anything I figured it out, I don't know if it was the correct way or more efficient way of doing it but I came up with this and it worked....
            <CheckBox
              name='chkInsulin'
              checked={this.props.checked}
              onChange={this.props.handleChange}
            />
            <label style={{ color: 'black' }} htmlFor='checkedInsulin'>
              Take Insulin
            </label>
            }

Comment: You might wanna change htmlFor to chkInsulin to make the Label work.